# IDBKeyRange.only() returns only first matching record

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am querying my database table as follows:

```
function getAllRecords(letter)
{
     var trans = db.transaction(["ObservableStates"],"readonly").objectStore("ObservableStates").index('letterIndex');
     //get all matching records
     var request = trans.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only([letter]));

     request.onsuccess = function(event)
     {
          var cursor = event.target.result;
          if(cursor)
          {
              count+=1;
              cursor.continue();
              console.log(cursor);
          }

      }

      request.onerror = function(event)
      {
          console.log('ERROR LOADING DATA FROM TABLE');
      }
      //delete all of the returned records
```

}

I have two records having the value of `letter` but only the first record is returned. `cursor.continue()` does not seem to work in this case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That should work, and I can't reproduce the problem. It's possible you're hitting a browser bug (which browser are you testing in?) or there's an incorrect assumption in your code that I'm not capturing here.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open('test');
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function() {
  var db = openRequest.result;
  var store = db.createObjectStore('ObservableStates');
  store.createIndex('letterIndex', 'p'); 
  store.put({p: ['a']}, 1);
  store.put({p: ['a']}, 2);
};
openRequest.onsuccess = function() {
  var db = openRequest.result;
  var trans = db.transaction('ObservableStates', 'readonly');
  var index = trans.objectStore('ObservableStates').index('letterIndex');
  var request = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(['a']));
  request.onsuccess = function() {
    var cursor = request.result;
    if (cursor) {
      console.log(cursor.key, cursor.primaryKey);
      cursor.continue();
    }
  }
};
```

And I see logged:

> - ["a"] 1
> - ["a"] 2

You may also want to do a `count([letter])` request against your index to confirm that it does have as many records as you expect.

Comment: Sorry for not following up this question. Strange solution, but I was doing a breakpoint inside the onSuccess callback (this code is inside a WebWorker.js file). When I removed the breakpoint everything worked well. Most probably it was because the WebWorker is an independent javascript file and was not updating when paused, whilst the main script was still running. Thanks